# remove appended element with jQuery and jQueryui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to append element using jqueryui autocomplete 
but I can't remove appended element
How can i do?

```
    $(function() {
    var products = [ 
        { "sn":"P00101","label":"Product 1"},
        { "sn":"P00102","label":"Product 2"},
        { "sn":"P00103","label":"Product 3"},
        { "sn":"P00104","label":"Product 4"}
    ]

    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: products,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.sn );
        $("<li>").html("["+ui.item.sn+"] "+ui.item.label+"<input type=text size=5><a href='#' class='remove'>Remove</a>").appendTo("#result");

        return false;
      }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>[" + item.sn + "] " + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };

    $(".remove").live("click",function() {
        $(this).parent("li").remove();
    });
  });
```

and my html source here

```
<input id="project">
<input type="hidden" id="project-id">

<h3>Result</h3> <ol id="result" class='lists'></ol>
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D98z9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.live` was deprecated from version `1.7` and removed in version `1.9`, you can use `.on()` instead.

Beside that, because your anchor have been added dynamically, the click event will not be available for these elements until you bind it. In this case, you can make use of **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

```
$("body").on("click",'.remove',function() {
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D98z9/1/)**